# How to get the value of a child object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the value of a child object of this object:

```
var data = {
    "5d55e9df-08f9-40db-bb46-64721c3b75ab":  {
        "value": "120"
    },
    "e7bc3558-f6b3-4797-ba72-ec9fe84986b2":  {
        "0":  {
            "value": ""
        }
    },
    "bookContent":  {
        "0":  {
            "value": "11 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
        },
        "1":  {
            "value": "remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get these values

1. The value of the `value` property under `bookContent` -> `1`
2. The value of `value` property under `5d55e9df-08f9-40db-bb46-64721c3b75ab`

This is what I have tried:

```
var mywantvalue = data[0].bookContent[0].value
```

But it's not working - I get "cannot get the value of undefined."

Comment: these aren't arrays - try `["0"]` and what is `data`?

Comment: `["0"]` is equal to `[0]`.  The code in the question is not a valid object so it's a bit hard to say if it's an array or what.

Comment: Seems like a valid object to me.  It's an interesting question really as it's one that anyone might encounter when working with external data sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example data is missing some closing brackets, which I assume is a copy and paste error.  Aside from that, the value can be accessed like this:

```
data.bookContent['1'].value;
```

Run the code snippet below to test.

It wasn't part of the question, but nodes in this format (i.e., key names 0,1,2,3,n) can be easily converted to an array with (as I recall) the array slice method. There's a post on SO about doing that.

You know, it's really not such a bad question.  I've seen this format in other sources of data and it does tend to throw people off who haven't seen it before.

```html
<html>
<body>
VALUE:  data.bookContent['1'].value
<div  id="book"></div>  
 <p>
JSON:
<xmp id="stdout"></xmp>
  
<script type="text/javascript">

  var data = 
{
"5d55e9df-08f9-40db-bb46-64721c3b75ab":  {
    "value": "120"
},
"e7bc3558-f6b3-4797-ba72-ec9fe84986b2":  {
    "0":  {
        "value": ""
    }
},
"bookContent":  {
    "0":  {
        "value": "11 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
    },
    "1":  {
        "value": "remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
    }
  
  
  }
  };
  

  
document.getElementById('stdout').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data,null,'  '); 
  
document.getElementById('book').innerHTML = data.bookContent['1'].value;
  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

All of your data is stored in a series of nested objects. Object properties are generally accessed by *dot notation* (`parent.child`), but can be accessed by *square bracket notation* (`parent["child"]`).

For property names that contain characters which are invalid in JS variable/property names, you *must* use square bracket notation.

As such, given the structure you showed, the desired data can be retrieved like

1. `data.bookContent["1"].value`
2. `data["5d55e9df-08f9-40db-bb46-64721c3b75ab"].value`